# What does the ground wire on a light's mounting bracket connect to?

Tags: electrical, lighting, grounding

I am replacing a chandelier in our dining room. I turned off the breaker and took the chandelier off and see two wires (hot and neutral):

[image]

The replacement light only has two wires (hot and neutral):

[image]

**But** it also has a mounting bracket that contains a ground wire to nowhere:

[image]

**What am I supposed to connect the other end of the ground wire to?!** The instructions don't make any sense. They just say to wrap the rest of the ground wire around the green screw/post. But I don't see what that would that accomplish!

Comment: Can you post a closeup shot of where the cable enters the box please?

Comment: There’s a screw in that junction box, perhaps for connecting ground if that box is connected to ground. What’s the resistance between the white neutral and the junction box? Open circuit or less than a few ohms? Less than a few ohms means that the box is grounded and that’s what you should connect the metal bracket and copper wire to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct solution here is:

1. Keep the breaker turned off
2. Tear out all the sheetrock and wall material between the light fixture and the main service panel (breaker)
3. Replace the wiring (possibly breaker) to be grounded (this includes running the ground wire all the way to the junction box in the ceiling over the light fixture)
4. Resheetrock and repair all the damaged walls between the light fixture and service panel
5. Now a third copper wire should be available to pigtail to the copper ground wire on the mounting bracket

However this is several hundred dollars and 20ish hours of my own labor or several thousands of dollars in contractor labor. Seeing that the light fixture was never grounded for the ~50 years the house has been here, I'm going to just:

1. Remove the copper ground wire from the mounting bracket altogether
2. Triple wrap the hot and neutral wires (after being pigtailed) in electrical tape and hope we continue to have the same luck as we've had for the 14 years we've already lived here

Comment: You are wrong about the futility of the ground strap.  It looks like you have a metal clad cable, which MIGHT have a bonding strip and might be correctly installed so that you have a good ground path through the box.  On the other hand, attaching the metal bar to the metal box with metal screws the strap is redundant so even if you (wrongly) discard it, you'll still get the benefit of any ground path through the box.  If you had a plastic box with NM cable it would be more obvious what to do with the strap.

Comment: You don't show it but presumably the fixture's metal parts are all connected together and will be connected to the metal bar via a metal threaded rod.  So the whole thing will hopefully be properly grounded.

Comment: Not the one that down voted, if  you really want a separate ground you can go to any grounded point that is fed from the same panel, single wire no need to tear things up. That’s if you even can use a ground I have been hired to replace wiring for a DIY type that wanted to ground his plastic pendant light, what can I say it was a slow week and he didn’t listen so I did what he wanted at 3X the cost of what would be legal if it was needed, what wiring method is entering the box?

Comment: Upvoted, since you had downvote from someone and accepted answer

Answer (score -4):

## Safety first

Most light fixtures have three wires, including a bare or a green ground wire.

Always turn off the power at the breaker or fuse box before you work on electricity. This keeps you safe from potential electric shock.

## The purpose of the ground wire

The ground wire is designed to protect you.

In the event that the live wire comes loose and touches the light fixture, the ground wire diverts the power and blows the breaker, instead of you feeling an electrical shock when you touch the fixture.

That’s the only purpose the ground wire serves. It’s a safety feature.

Source: https://dfarq.homeip.net/connect-a-2-wire-light-fixture-without-ground/

Comment: Sorry but this isn't an answer. I mention at the top of my question that I shut the power off at the breaker. I also mention that the fixture only has 2 wires, and I even provided a picture of such. Also this question doesn't ask what the purpose of a ground wire is, it asks what I should do with the other end of the ground wire thats on the mounting bracket. Honestly was the question even read?

Comment: The copper wire in your hand should be connected to the bare copper wire that is bundle with the hot (black) and white (neutral) wire.    Understanding the purpose provides the insight as to why and how wire should be connected to maintain safety.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Is a bare copper wire bundled with the black and white wire?

Comment: Thanks @gatorback (+1) when you say "_...should be connected to the bare copper wire that is bundle with the hot (black) and white (neutral) wire_"...where in any of my photos do you see this copper wire? I'm appreciative that you are trying to help me (truly!). To reiterate, coming out of the ceiling junction are only two wires (hot + neutral). The fixture itself only has two wires (hot + neutral). There is only 1 bare copper wire. One end of it is wrapped around the post on the mounting bracket. The other is just...going to nowhere.

Comment: In your first photograph, there is a black and white wire.  As you indicate, no third bare copper wire.  There's a good chance (if it wired to code) that the third bare wire is there and  you may need to remove the box to expose said third wire. Usually there is a 3rd bare copper wire in the ceiling for you to connect the bare copper wire of the luminaire part in the third photo.

Comment: Our house is definitely not wired to code, and when I removed the old light fixture there was no ground wire in the old fixture nor anything in the ceiling junction box. I'm wondering if I can just remove the ground wire from the green screw since there is nothing to connect it to.

Comment: Before some time in the early 70's grounding was not a requirement on all outlets (and lights) - so assuming the house was built (and wired) in the 60's or earlier it's not at all unusual to find 2-wire cables with no bare ground wire included.

Comment: You could wire the luminaire with only the hot & neutral, however, you would be wise to replace the box with a plastic, non conductive box.   After binding the hot with a wire nut, you could also wrap it in electric tape to minimize the chances of the hot breaking loose and becoming a shock hazard

Comment: OK thanks, so just remove the bare copper wire thats wrapped around the green screw? And yes this home was mid-1960s so its reassuring to know that was common back then.

Comment: The copper wire in photo 3 does not matter if it is not connected to anything: remove it if you like.   I really hope that for your (safety) sake that you understand the safety purpose of wiring said wire: it provides a mechanism to short circuit and trip the circuit breaker should the hot touch the fixture.   It prevents the fixture from becoming a shock hazard.